# How to get Shift+X / Alt+X keys in Curses ?

Tags: ruby, curses

I am currently using this code to grab key-strokes, but I am missing e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys like
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, etc.

```
  require 'curses'

  Curses.noecho
  Curses.raw
  Curses.stdscr.keypad(true)
  Curse.nonl

  count = 0
  loop do
    count = (count + 1) % 20
    key = Curses.getch
    break if key == ?\C-c
    Curses.setpos(count,0)
    Curses.addstr("#{key.inspect}     ");
  end
```

Is there any way to capture them all ?

Also: how can I distinguish <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which give the same key-codes (`10`/`13`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> also: how can distinguish ctrl+j / ctrl+m from ctr+enter / enter,
>   which give the same key-codes (10/13)

Long story short - you cannot. The terminal will almost-certainly yield the same bytes for each. Please read

http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/

That said, if you are feeling especially brave, you can try my `libtermkey`

http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/

which will at least correctly parse things like `Ctrl-arrow`. It doesn't (yet) have a Ruby binding, but the presence of both Perl and Python ones would suggest it should be quite easy to write one.

Finally if you're feeling even braver you can run the terminal I wrote, `pangoterm`, which has generic ways to encode any arbitrarily modified Unicode keys, so it can distinguish Ctrl-m from Enter, etc...

https://launchpad.net/pangoterm

However, outside of these, the answer remains "you cannot".