# How to get Ctrl, Shift or Alt with getch() ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

How to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> with `getch()` ncurses ?

Do I miss something in the man ?

Comment: Control, shift, and alt do not generate input, they modify other input.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I remember many games where you could use any of those keys for individual actions. Every key has some sort of unique scan code I believe.

Comment: @KerrekSB they don't generate input to stdin though. You can test whether they are _down_ or not (i.e. Windows has `GetAsyncKeyState`), but that's working with the keyboard, not with input like `getch` does.

Comment: This question should be rephrased. Now it's mostly the nearly literal repetition of one sentence.

Comment: it's unclear if you want the Alt key by itself or as a modifier (alt+c).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Amazing how sometimes the right answer gets demoted, and answers that "authoritatively" give up get promoted... With a bit of creativity, key_name actually holds the right key to figuring this out, with one caveat - that SHIFT/ALT/CTRL are pressed with other keys at the same time:

- First, for "normal keys" such as the printable ones, you can easily detect shift because it uppercases.
- For special keys, e.g. KEY_LEFT, you will see that the code generated when SHIFT is selected is actually KEY_SLEFT. ditto for KEY_RIGHT. Unfortunately, no such luck for KEY_UP/KEY_DOWN , which seem unfazed by SHIFT. So you can distinguish by the returned char from getch() - the KEY_S.. implies shift was pressed.
- For ALT (what's not trapped by X or the Aqua Windowmanager, at least), keyname will convert the key to an M... something.
- For CTRL you'll get a "^" preceding the actual key name. E.g ^R for key 18

So you can now figure out the key codes for your switch(getch) statements, etc,  by a simple snippet:

```
ch = getch(); endwin(); printf("KEY NAME : %s - %d\n", keyname(ch),ch);
```

and that's that. Think before definitively saying "can't". Maybe there's a way that's less obvious.

Comment: This doesn't help with writing code which works across multiple keyboard layouts.  For example `Shift+2` can generate different characters depending on the layout.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. FYI and to confirm the obvious, this approach might be specific to C (as the question was tagged). I tried this in Python on Linux and Ctrl was not converted into a '^'.

Comment: That's because Python bindings "cook" the codes further.

Comment: #1: Not so. When I hit shift-return to indicate a line break in multi-line input and not a dialog complete condition, I get '\r' in either case.

Comment: `KEY_SR` and `KEY_SF` seem to result from SHIFT+UP and SHIFT+DOWN, respectively.

Answer (score 13):

At least for the control modifier there is a simple solution. Curses had been derived from vi source code, in which you find the following (see
https://github.com/n-t-roff/ex-1.1/blob/master/ex.h line 77 and https://github.com/n-t-roff/ex-1.1/blob/master/ex_vops.c line 445):

```
#ifndef CTRL
#define CTRL(c) ((c) & 037)
#endif

switch(getch()) {
case CTRL('r'):
    /* key ctrl-r (i.e. ^R) pressed */
```

Dependend on used includes `CTRL` may or may not already been defined in your code.

Comment: I didn't try this out, but it would be nice to know why this was downvoted.

Comment: It's because it should be an uppercase R @JayantBhawal

Answer (score 7):

(To roughly copy my answer from [How to get Shift+X / Alt+X keys in Curses ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684739/how-to-get-shiftx-altx-keys-in-curses/9775675#9775675))

Long story short - you cannot. The modifier keys are just that - modifiers. They do not exist in their own right, they modify some other (printing) key that you might press.

That said, if you are feeling especially brave, you can try my [libtermkey](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) which will at least correctly parse things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd>.

Finally if you're feeling even braver you can run the terminal I wrote, [pangoterm](https://launchpad.net/pangoterm), which has generic ways to encode any arbitrarily modified Unicode keys, so it can distinguish <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> from <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, etc...

However, outside of these, the answer remains "you cannot".

Answer (score 6):

Agreeing (partly) with @leonerd, ncurses will ***only*** give you those keys as they are used as *modifiers* to other keys (ignoring the ASCII *escape* character which some people confuse with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).  Some specific devices can be told to give this information (e.g., Linux console as documented in [console_ioctl(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html)), but that's not a problem that ncurses will solve for you.

Refer to the ncurses FAQ [How can I use shift- or control-modifiers?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys) for a long answer.

But short: ncurses doesn't tell you if a given modifier was used (except for special cases where there were well-known uses of <kbd>shift</kbd>), but rather its terminal descriptions provide the information either by

- multiplying the actual function keys by combinations of shift- and control-modifiers, or by
- using names based on xterm's PC-style function keys (shift is 2, alt is 3, control is 5, etc), to provide the information.

There are two approaches because the first uses an array of no more than 60 function keys (good enough for shift- and control-combinations), while the other just uses *user-defined* names).

All of these modified keys give multiple bytes; an application using `keypad()` (of course) in ncurses would get a single number.  In the latter case, the keycodes are determined at runtime.

That applies mainly to the *special keys* (function-, editing- and cursor-keys).  For regular keys, one might assume that [`keyname`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name) gives some special behavior, but reading the description it does not:

- it reports the ASCII control characters (which you can do using the `iscntrl` macro), and
- makes assumptions about meta (which only are useful for `xterm`, of the terminals you are likely to use), and
- offers no help for the <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier.

Of terminals... all have the modifier information available internally, but terminals generally do not have a way to pass this information to applications.  `xterm` can do this using the [`modifyOtherKeys`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys) resource,

```
   modifyOtherKeys (class ModifyOtherKeys)
           Like modifyCursorKeys, tells xterm to construct an escape
           sequence for other keys (such as "2") when modified by
           Control-, Alt- or Meta-modifiers.  This feature does not apply
           to function keys and well-defined keys such as ESC or the
           control keys.  The default is "0":

           0    disables this feature.

           1    enables this feature for keys except for those with well-
                known behavior, e.g., Tab, Backarrow and some special
                control character cases, e.g., Control-Space to make a
                NUL.

           2    enables this feature for keys including the exceptions
                listed.
```

which corresponds to a control sequence, seen in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_):

```
CSI > Ps; Ps m
          Set or reset resource-values used by xterm to decide whether
          to construct escape sequences holding information about the
          modifiers pressed with a given key.  The first parameter iden-
          tifies the resource to set/reset.  The second parameter is the
          value to assign to the resource.  If the second parameter is
          omitted, the resource is reset to its initial value.
            Ps = 0  -> modifyKeyboard.
            Ps = 1  -> modifyCursorKeys.
            Ps = 2  -> modifyFunctionKeys.
            Ps = 4  -> modifyOtherKeys.
```

but (being an xterm-specific feature), there's no reason to use it in ncurses: it would needlessly complicate `getch`.

Answer (score 3):

I use a double getch() trick.

```
#define ESC 27
int altpressed;

int sgetch()
{
  int t;
  
    t=getch();
    if ( t == ESC ) { // possible alt held down
     t=bgetch(10);
     if ( t == -1 ) // escape key pressed
      return ESC;
     altpressed=1;
    }

 return t;
}
```

Now bgetch() :

```
// getch with block/unblock
int bgetch(int delay)
{
  int t;  
    
   if ( delay != BLOCK )
    blockunblockgetch(delay);
  
   t=getch();
   
   blockunblockgetch();
   
 return t;
}
```

..and blockunblockgetch() :

```
// block, unblock getch
int blockunblockgetch(int delay)
{
  wtimeout(win1, delay);
  
 return ( delay == -1 ) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

What you have is simply a getch() that if ESC is detected, it blocks the next getch() for 10ms. If there is another char in the stream, it will return that char (in int) with altpressed (a global variable) set to 1. You can then utilize the alt+key checking altpressed. SHIFT and CTRL are easier to detect, they are recognized as single ints with NCURSES.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `key_name( c )` to turn the key generated from `getch()` into something that shows you the state of the ctrl-modifier.

For example this code shows "^R" if you press ctrl-r:

```
while( true )
{
   char c = getch();
   if ( ERR == c )
      break;

   const char *name = key_name( c );

   move( 2, 2 );
   clear();
   printw( "You entered: %s             ", name );
   refresh();

}
```

Comment: `getch` returns a `chartype`, not a `char`.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but for anyone still looking...
You CAN do this on Windows (At least on my version).
Simply interpret getch as bytes-like integer then as a string.

```
str(getchvariablehere)
```

For example, Ctrl+A is 1 on my keyboard.
Its a bit tedious, but you can check any combo with this method.

My wording may be off, but this method seems to work with raster fonts that can't display bytes as arbitrary unicode.