# How to detect curses ALT + key combinations in python

Tags: python, curses

New to python here and using the curses import. I want to detect key combinations like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and similar. Currently, I am using `getch()` to receive a key and then printing it in a curses window. The value does not change for <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. How can I detect the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key combinations?

```
import curses

def Main(screen):
   foo = 0
   while foo == 0: 
      ch = screen.getch()
      screen.addstr (5, 5, str(ch), curses.A_REVERSE)
      screen.refresh()
      if ch == ord('q'):
         foo = 1

curses.wrapper(Main)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
import curses

def Main(screen):
   while True:
      ch = screen.getch()
      if ch == ord('q'):
         break
      elif ch == 27: # ALT was pressed
         screen.nodelay(True)
         ch2 = screen.getch() # get the key pressed after ALT
         if ch2 == -1:
            break
         else:
            screen.addstr(5, 5, 'ALT+'+str(ch2))
            screen.refresh()
         screen.nodelay(False)

curses.wrapper(Main)
```

Comment: OP, ^ this is the best method I've seen.  Otherwise, you may not like what they say, but checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750588/how-to-get-ctrl-shift-or-alt-with-getch-ncurses
Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps getch() is not the correct function call to use. I recall it being quite limited for some things in the C language. Perhaps a better question would be how to read raw scan codes... Also, the example does not seem to work pasted in. Hmm..

Comment: Actually the code works fine pasted in. My mistake. I was expecting it to print all keys, not just ALT+ combinations. Thanks!

Comment: Update: a while after using this code, I noticed pressing the [ESC] key would generate a 1 second delay. I needed to call os.environ['ESCDELAY'] = "25" prior to entering curses.wrapper.