# detect special keypress (Alt,Ctrl,F1,etc.)

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x

How to catch special keypress in Python 3.4.3 Ubuntu Console?
I found this:

```
import tty, sys, termios, select
def setup_term(fd, when=termios.TCSAFLUSH):
    mode = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    mode[tty.LFLAG] = mode[tty.LFLAG] & ~(termios.ECHO | TERMIOS.ICANON)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, when, mode)
def getch(timeout=None):
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        setup_term(fd)
        try:
            rw, wl, xl = select.select([fd],[],[],timeout)
        except select.error:
            return
        if rw:
            return sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

but it doesn't detect press of F1, Alt, Ctrl, and similar.
I would like to not adding any packages, if it's possible.
sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module might help you if you want to build a text user interface. This example prints a key code for each pressed key:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(1)
    while True:
        keycode=stdscr.getch()
        stdscr.addstr("%i\n" % keycode)
        stdscr.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

For special keys like F1, enter or arrow keys, compare the key code with some of the constants like curses.KEY_F1: https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#constants

You will not be able to capture some modifier keys like alt or control though. This is not possible with regular terminals, see [How to get CTRL, Shift or Alt with getch() ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750588/how-to-get-ctrl-shift-or-alt-with-getch-ncurses)