# How to capture ctrl+shift+a (a-z) in c

Tags: c, terminal, console, curses

How to capture ctrl+shift+a (a-z) in a c console app.
I've tried getch, kbhit samples, curses raw mode. But the samples couldn't differentiate ctrl+a from ctrl+shift+a

Comment: I think you might get answers "impossible" (but that is only a guess, I do not really know). I hence propose to describe what you want to achieve, how using your program should look like. With that, you could get answers "impossible, but you can do .....". Maybe have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Related: [How to get Ctrl, Shift or Alt with getch() ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750588/how-to-get-ctrl-shift-or-alt-with-getch-ncurses)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.